# Create CryptoJS AES Cipher Encryptor to Decrypt in .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, aes, md5, cryptojs

I'm trying to create Encryption/Decryption that will work between server/client. I have CryptoJS for my client side and ASP.Net (VB.Net) for my server side. The server side is being used in numerous places so cannot change so the CryptoJS needs work around what the .NET is doing. I can't get my CryptoJS to imitate the .NET 100%.

FYI the .NET code can't change, the JS has to match .NET functionality.

> *Code removed upon request*

#### The error I get in .NET when I try and decrypt the client side encryption:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

#### Extra Information

If I just push through a Hex as the key (remove the `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)`), I don't get enough characters (seems to change to 128bit instead of 256bit).

The actual data returned by MD5_Key in JS *seems to* match Validate_MD5 in .NET...

Am I trying to achieve the impossible?

Comment: Interesting...am not a crypto person, but _"keys and secrets"_ in _client side script_ make me shudder...

Comment: @EdSF It'll be in an app, so less easy for predators, but obfuscation will be used ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CryptoJS supports only AES which is basically Rijndael but limited to the block size of 128-bit. It supports key sizes of 128, 192 and 256-bit. You .net code uses Rijndael with a block size of 256 which is not supported by CryptoJS. CryptoJS happily takes the big IV and only uses the first 16 bytes.

You will have to find another library that supports this since you can't change the .net code.

Comment: I don't know any library off the top of my head that does this.

Comment: Apologies for my lack of understanding, but I don't understand how I've managed to create a 256-bit key using a string, but if I use a hex, I can only make a 128-bit key? I'm guessing the size of the generated key is nothing to do with the block size?

Comment: That's right, the key size has nothing to do with the block size.

Comment: How can I generate a 256-bit key in the .NET with 128-bit block size? I tried changing just the block size field and the IV but it just generates a 128-bit key

Comment: I really don't see how `MD5_Key` and `Validate_MD5` would do the same operation, but you say you checked. I'm not familiar with .net, so I don't know what `ReDim Preserve ReturnValue(BlockSize - 1)` is supposed to do. I suspect that you can remove everything between the first and last line of the `MD5_Key` body. CryptoJS also takes the native data representation instead of some string encoding. Also note that `Hex.parse(MD5Key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)` probably drops some bytes because they are not printable.

Comment: `ReDim Preserve ReturnValue(BlockSize - 1)` simply makes the byte array the correct size, AFAIK. If there are too many it will remove them, if there aren't enough it will add them. I'm replicating this with the `for` loop in `MD5_Key`, and the `substring` immediately after. I actually have already removed the `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);` as that was me testing. I just noted that if I used Hex, I didn't get enough characters, but if I used a string, I did. I guess I was trying to hack a way around the 256-bit problem :(